Asymptotic expansion of a differential equation
I am a physicist studying a nonhomogenous differential equation of the general form
\begin{equation}
a(x)f^{(n)}(x) +b(x)f^{(n-1)}(x) +\dots + c(x)f(x) = \mathcal{F}(f(x),x),
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $a(x)$, $b(x)$, $\dots$, $c(x)$ are rational functions and $\mathcal{F}(f(x),x)$ is a complicated expression. The equation would be linear without this term.  Crucially, the explicit form of $\mathcal{F}(f(x),x)$ is not known unless one does an aymptotic expansion for $x \gg1$, in which case one has
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}(f(x),x) = \frac{\log(x)}{x^4} + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{x^5} \right).
\end{equation}
Inserting this approximation into the equation makes it linear.
The solutions to the differential equation are expected to go to zero at large $x$, and so do the coefficient functions $a(x)$, $b(x)$, $\dots$, $c(x)$. However, whereas the left-hand side of $(1)$ is exact, substituting $\mathcal{F}(f(x),x) \to \log(x)/x^4$ on the right-hand side assumes an asymptotic expansion. This brings me to the question: is it possible to do the corresponding asymptotic expansion on the rest of the equation, from the known forms of $a(x)$, $b(x)$, $c(x)$? In other words,

Is it possible to, from a given differential equation whose solution is regular at $x\to \infty$, write another (hopefully simpler) equation for the asymptotic behavior of the solution?

There is no dimensionless number to use as expansion parameter for perturbation theory, but only some terms of the asymptotic expansion of $f(x)$ at infinity are needed (no matching with the "internal" solution is required). I expect $f(x)$ to be of the form
\begin{equation}
f(x) = f_0+\frac{f_1(x)}{x}+\frac{f_2(x)}{x^2} + \dots \, , \hspace{1cm} \text{for $x\gg1$},
\end{equation}
where the dominant dependence on $x$ of each term is given the power of $1/x$, but the $f_i(x)$ may still have some milder dependence on $x$. It is possible to expand each term of $(1)$ in powers of $1/x$ and look at each power separately, but I do know if that is a valid approach.
